# Jquery AJAX returning 404 (fastapi)

Tags: jquery, ajax, fastapi

I have a button in main.html which, when clicked, should take what is returned by the fastApi listener in main.py and log the data.
But (when launching via the chrome button in pycharm) I'm getting a

```
POST http://localhost:63342/a/ 404 (Not Found)
```

**EDIT:**

when launching via uvicorn, I'm getting:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/test.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm not sure if this has more information in it.

I don't see my problem. What am I missing?
Thanks

**main.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import RedirectResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import pandas as pd

# App
app = FastAPI()

# Link to the Templates
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

# Home Page (routes to the forecast page by default)
@app.get("/")
def home(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("home.html", {"request": request})

@app.post("/a/")
def bla(request: Request):
    return "asdf"
```

**test.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '#execute', function(){
        $.ajax({
                    url: "/a/",
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
    });
});
```

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>QIM</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-r4NyP46KrjDleawBgD5tp8Y7UzmLA05oM1iAEQ17CSuDqnUK2+k9luXQOfXJCJ4I" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="test.js"></script>

    </head>
    
    <body>
        <button type="button" id="execute" class="btn btn-primary">Run</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the `/a/` endpoint work if you change it to `get` and just open `/a/` in your browser?

Comment: @MatsLindh yes indeed

Comment: You're going to have to add a static route and use `url_for` to get the url to your static file.  See https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/ for details

Answer (score 0):

I simply changed the include statement from

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script>{% include 'test.js' %}</script>
```

and this worked